# What is a rigorous definition of what should be an "awaitable" task?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to understand `async`-`await` at a deep level. Whenever I see examples of how it works, the example uses an `await`able method called `LongRunningTask` or similar and in it is a `Task.Delay` or a `new WebClient().Download("http://google.com")` or something similar. I'm trying to figure out what would be a rigorous definition of what should be awaited on. It can't simply be "a long-running task", because a long-running task could be something like finding the maximum subarray of an array of size 1,000,000,000, which wouldn't confer any performance benefit to being `await`ed on if it's true that `async`-`await` doesn't create any new threads.

From what I understand, if you have something like

```
var task = LongRunningTask();
DoSomething();
int x = DoSomethingElse();
int y = await task;
int z = x + y;
```

then the chunk

```
DoSomething();
int x = DoSomethingElse();
```

is what you're hinting to the compiler that

> "Hey, compiler, if you can verify that this chunk doesn't have any
>   dependencies on `LongRunningTask` and vice-versa, then you can start
>   dividing your work between `LongRunningTask` and this chunk of code.
>   It you haven't finished `LongRunningTask` by the time you finish this
>   chunk of code, then just work on finishing `LongRunningTask`, hence
>   why I'm telling you `await` it."

Can you help straighten me out?

Comment: Async/await was added at 4.5 to give programmers that target WinRT (aka UWP, aka Modern UI, aka Store, aka Phone) a fighting chance to write correct code.  It has a *very* rigorous definition, anything that might take more than 50 milliseconds.   You can probably be a bit more selective than *anything* and 50 msec is fairly draconian, I personally use 1 second as the "too-long" limit and will throw in an hourglass cursor if reasonable.  Avoiding draining a small battery is an entirely different consideration, then it gets draconian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`await` is less magic than you think. In your example, the decision on whether to use other threads, or I/O completion routines, etc, isn't in *any* of the code you've shown.

The implementation of `LongRunningTask`, by being a method that returns an already started `Task`, has made any complex decisions about *how* and *when* that `Task` gets completed.

All that `await` does is to wait (as its name implies) for something that has *already* been started to complete.

Now, **if** `LongRunningTask` is implemented by creating new Tasks, and those tasks are using the default scheduler that uses that thread pool, *and* if your current method is already running on a thread pool thread *and* some of the tasks created by `LongRunningTask` are waiting for a thread pool thread to become available, then it is *possible* that the very same thread that had been running your code becomes available when the `await` is encountered and will be used to start running one of the waiting tasks. But this is mostly something you don't need to think about.

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of your question, a long-running task is any task that involves Input/Output (I/O).

This is the par excellence class of tasks that can be awaited, because what usually happens with I/O is that the computer issues instructions to commence the I/O, and then simply waits (usually in a low-CPU state) for the I/O to complete.

So, `new WebClient().Download("http://google.com")` is a good example of a task that involves I/O, because in order to perform this task, the machine will need to prepare a request to google.com, start sending it over a socket, wait for the request to be completely sent, then wait for a response to start arriving, then wait until the response has completely arrived.

However, this definition is not strict; even finding the maximum subarray of an array of size 1,000,000,000 could be a long-running task, if it was implemented by spawning a new thread, because as far as the calling thread is concerned, we would have a very similar scenario: we set-up the operation, (spawn the new thread, passing it the array to be searched,) and then wait for the results, doing nothing.

**Edit**

In light of the above, the maximum-subarray-of-huge-array example could be thought of as a red herring, because for the purpose of async-await, the question of whether it is or it isn't a long-running task depends on whether it is launched in a separate thread or not.

So, a much better definition of a long-running task could be:

> Any task that takes such an amount of time to complete that it is
>   undesirable to block waiting for in the currently executing thread.

So, for example, if you are writing an interactive (GUI) application, and you want to guarantee a 200 millisecond response time to your human user, then any task that is bound to take longer than that is a long-running task: you start it, await for it, and for as long as it is running your GUI is still responsive.  On the other hand, if you are writing a batch processing job which is meant to run overnight to crunch some big data, then virtually no task is worth being considered as a long-running task.

Comment: Does `Task.Delay` involve I/O?

Comment: No, it does not.  It just sets up a timer which will fire later, and then it immediately returns.  When the timer fires, the awaiting completes.  But they only use it in the examples as a **placeholder** for a real long-running task.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in above answer, Task CAN fire up different threads and await waits result for that particular tasks.

Usually Tasks like API calls which is completely independent of amount of processing power i.e. even if you have maximum RAM, CPU has no or little impact of the response you are seeking i.e. IO bound latency which is Task that needs to be done. And those tasks are internally completed by worker thread and generally should be awaited

Reference: Essential C# 6.0 (5th Edition)

Comment: 1) If you want to reference another answer, it's usually better to include a link to it rather than to use positional phrasing (such as "above"), since answers can be rearranged due to voting, randomization, etc. 2) await does *not* fire up threads. await doesn't *start* anything. await always works with "awaitables", and those awaitable items (such as Tasks) represent work that has *already* been started by something else.

Comment: Yes - the important distinction here is that `await` doesn't know or care whether the underlying process is using threads or not; it just cares that it should return an incomplete task now and carry on later. *Generally speaking* (i.e. in the majority use case) there is probably no thread but that is simply because the majority use case is inherently asynchronous tasks like making HTTP requests.